# Cómo poner la clausula DISTINCT en una consulta en MVC

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

Estoy trabajando con `MVC` y quiero hacer esta consulta a la Base de Datos, pero necesito que no me repita los datos de la consulta. ¿Como puedo utilizar el `DISTINCT`?

Código:

```
public function getSup($sup_name){
   $this->db->select DISTINCT('roster_sup');
   $this->db->where('roster_sm', $sup_name);  
   $data = $this->db->get('ol_roster');
   return $data;
}
```

Comment: mas que nada estas usando un orm y para poder ayudarte es necesario saber q orm estas usando o de que framework y por lo que veo es codeigniter no?

Comment: si es codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
$sup_named = '123';
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('roster_sup');
$this->db->where('roster_sm', $sup_name); 
$query = $this->db->get('ol_roster');
```

Comment: gracias me sirvio